# If the brain can't think, what does?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, mind, thinking

I often read in philosophical discussions (in here and elsewhere) the word "brain" connected to higher level human functions, like thought, even consciousness. If this was a scientific place, I certainly wouldn't be surprised. But this is a philosophical place.

So, I made a small "research" in the Web on the subject of where does **thought** take place. I tried to collect information from sources/references that are *generally accepted as standard and/or reliable*. I present below the results of this "research", in a concise form. (Comments within brackets [] are mine.)

**Human brain**
(*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_brain*)

*The **philosophy of the mind** studies such issues as the problem of understanding **consciousness** and the **mind–body problem**. The relationship between the brain and the mind is a significant challenge both philosophically and scientifically. This is because of the difficulty in explaining how mental activities, such as **thoughts** and emotions, can be implemented by physical structures such as neurons and synapses, or by any other type of physical mechanism. This difficulty was expressed by Gottfried Leibniz in the analogy known as *Leibniz's Mill:
"One is obliged to admit that perception and what depends upon it is inexplicable on mechanical principles, that is, by figures and motions. In imagining that there is a machine whose construction would enable it to think, to sense, and to have perception, one could conceive it enlarged while retaining the same proportions, so that one could enter into it, just like into a windmill. Supposing this, one should, when visiting within it, find only parts pushing one another, and never anything by which to explain a perception."* (Leibniz, *Monadology*)

*Doubt about the possibility of a mechanistic explanation of **thought** drove René Descartes, and most other philosophers along with him, to dualism: the belief that the mind is to some degree independent of the brain.*

*There has always, however, been a strong argument in the opposite direction. There is clear empirical evidence that physical manipulations of, or injuries to, the brain (for example by drugs or by lesions, respectively) can affect the mind in potent and intimate ways. In the 19th century, the case of Phineas Gage, a railway worker who was injured by a stout iron rod passing through his brain, convinced both researchers and the public that cognitive functions were localized in the brain. Following this line of thinking, a large body of empirical evidence for a close relationship between brain activity and mental activity has led most neuroscientists and contemporary philosophers to be materialists, believing that mental phenomena are ultimately the result of, or reducible to, physical phenomena.*

[Comment: This case helped to convince people that mental functions were localized in the brain. This is also where Science (with capital "S") had initially based its "belief" (i\unscientific concept!) that **thought** was created and processed by the brain! But let's see how the subject has evolved in Science since then ...]

---

**Ask a Scientist: Neurons help explain how our brains think**
*(https://eu.pressconnects.com/story/news/local/2019/03/18/ask-scientist-how-do-thoughts-work-our-brain/3153303002/)*

*Although the science of brain cell communication is well-understood, the complexity of **thought** processes is not well-defined.
The brain is primarily composed of neurons, which are cells that generate electrical impulses for communication.
Neurons release brain chemicals, known as neurotransmitters, which generate these electrical signals in neighboring neurons. The electrical signals propagate like a wave to thousands of neurons, which leads to **thought** formation.
One theory explains that **thoughts** are generated when neurons fire.*

[Comment: Well, they don't mention any other theory!]

---

**The Brain Building Blocks**
*(https://www.livestrong.com/article/202078-human-brain-thinking-process/)*

*The brain's primary building element starts with the brain cells known as neurons. Chemical processes in the brain send out messages through the neurons that determine the mental processes along with **thinking**. Cells called glia exist between the neurons in the brain. Mark Treadwell, an educator from New Zealand at I-learnt Website, indicates the glia interact with the neurons and hormones chemically in the production of **thought**. The motor neurons produce the action in our muscles and the sensory neurons connect to our five senses.*

**Thinking Process**
*The American College of Radiology and the Radiology Society describe functional MRI as a diagnostic procedure that can determine precisely the location of **thought** processes in the brain. A positron emission topography scan also can document images of the brain during a range of **thought** processes. The future has promise for new insights into the **thinking** process using these new technologies.*

**Reasoning Process**
[They just describe it. They don't connect it to the brain in any way ... I wonder why ...]

---

**Brain Anatomy and How the Brain Works**
*(https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/conditions-and-diseases/anatomy-of-the-brain)*

*The brain is a complex organ that controls **thought**, memory, emotion, touch, motor skills, vision, breathing, temperature, hunger and every process that regulates our body. Together, the brain and spinal cord that extends from it make up the central nervous system, or CNS.

New studies are exploring the cerebellum’s roles in **thought**, emotions and social behavior, as well as its possible involvement in addiction, autism and schizophrenia.*

[Comment: This is all about "thought". In a text of about 2,000 words. Isn't that incredible?]

---

The following section is all mine.

**Conclusion**

This how much the scientific world understands **thought**! And they are so arrogant that, even if they are so evidently ignorant on the subject, they insist placing **thought** in the brain, which they study since eons , having found maybe everything they could about at this date. And this is most probably because, as pure materialists, they think, *"Where else can it be located?"* What has happened to the scientific method: observation -> hypothesis -> testing (experimentation) -> proof? I have not found that such a thing has been applied in the case of **thought**. And even if they arrive in explaining some simple process of **thought**, e.g. "thinking of a tree", what could one say about the whole range of human **thought**, including higher-level of mind/thinking processes, such as imagination, computing, reasoning and so on?

So, my position is that **thought is neither created by nor is taking place in the brain**.

And my three part question is "**What** is thinking, **how** thought is created and **where** does it take place?".

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151394/discussion-on-question-by-apostolos-if-the-brain-cant-think-what-does); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking about thoughts as your experience of perceiving stuff, having emotions, formulating phrases in your head, remembering past perceptions or imagining unknown ones, taking decisions, etc... those are not an will never be an object of scientific study because your experience can't be shared or compared with other people's experience. The only thing we can share are words describing this experience and measurements of biological activity correlated to those experiences (like measuring the activity of your brain when you see a flower, etc).

This is probably why you won't see much scientific publication about where in the brain thoughts are occuring. Actually, I'd be very wary of such a publication, "thoughts" being such a vaguely defined concept. It looks like you are asking for the impossible.

Now, if we are talking about where in the brain are processed each of the functions listed above (perception, emotions, language, memory, imagination, decision making...), we have a pretty good idea of what part of the brain does what, if only because we can study how damage in a given part of the brain modifies those functions, or we can have medical imagery of what part gets active under a given circumstance. People under invasive procedures like brain tumors treatment have been studied, we know how to provoke emotions, make people sad or feel bliss with an electrode, even if it's not done often for obvious ethical considerations.

[Antonio Damasio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Damasio) has written several pretty accessible books about the topic.

Comment: thank you for responding to the topic. I'm not asking for the impossible. Please see my recent answer to the topic, where I explain why science is wrong about thinking and how "thinking" --the mind, in general-- works.

Comment: @Apostolos "science and all the specialists are wrong, only me is right" never heard of that one... What could go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The mind and brain is a well-heeded distinction around which the issue of [mind-body duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_dualism) has existed since at least the Pre-Socratics. So, when you ask, if the brain doesn't hold thoughts, what does? The canonical answer is the mind. The relationship between the brain and mind have historically been contentious. When philosophy was largely rooted in idealism, the minds were responsible for causing physical reality. Today, physicalism is the dominant metaphysical position, so brains somehow seem to be the grounding of the mind. **In [panpsychism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panpsychism), thoughts might be seen as permeating the very nature of the universe itself, which again has become somewhat interesting to philosophers.** From WP:

> Recent interest in the hard problem of consciousness and developments in the fields of neuroscience, psychology, and quantum physics have revived interest in panpsychism in the 21st century.

It should be noted that there are still aspects of thoughts and their relationship to the brain that are controversial. For instance, philosophers engage in vigorous debate about [mental causation (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mental-causation/). When we think, does it actually affect the brain at all? Not according to [epiphenomenalists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphenomenalism). **My position is in alignment with [embodied and extended cognition (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/embodied-cognition/), which is to say that thinking really is a product of the brain situated in the body in communication with the resources in the environment using the medium of language which is a social product.** Thinking that thought is some substance of the brain, like ketchup resides in a bottle, to me, seems take the [conceptual metaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_metaphor) that thought occurs "in" anything at all too far.

**So, thoughts are often thought to be caused by the brain today, but there are a number of philosophical positions that challenge some or all of this metaphysical presupposition**.

Answer (score 1):

I will primarily cover the issues with the body of the post.

> "belief" (i\unscientific concept!)

Knowledge is commonly defined as true justified belief, and science pursues knowledge. I personally would formulate it as true-justified belief, because can there be a false justified belief? By this definition, beliefs are not unscientific as long as they have a justification of truthness.

> And they are so arrogant that, even if they are so evidently ignorant on the subject, they insist placing **thought** in the brain, which they study since eons, having found maybe everything they could about at this date.

Neurology is not the only scientific field that has open problems. Even older fields such as physics and chemistry still have open problems. Will you be arguing that just because they were studying the world for so long and there is still no theory of everything, then laws of physics are just some academic hoax?

> What has happened to the scientific method: observation -> hypothesis -> testing (experimentation) -> proof?

As was said above in your post, what has led scientists to believe the thought is located in the brain is an observation of brain damage affecting the thought. A hypothesis was made, subsequent testing was performed with positive results.

On the other hand, empirical science, even hard science, does not make proofs. It's not mathematics, there are no infalliably known premises from which you can just correctly derive a conlusion. Empirical science merely produces strong evidence. And there is a strong evidence showing that altering the brain affects thought.

> And even if they arrive in explaining some simple process of **thought**, e.g. "thinking of a tree", what could one say about the whole range of human **thought**, including higher-level of mind/thinking processes, such as imagination, computing, reasoning and so on?

They could say that more complex thoughts are represented by more complex structural properties in the brain. The complexity of that seems beyond our ability to comperehend things. But this issue appears not only with a human brain, there is a problem even in explaining why modern AIs behave the way they do. Even though, I suppose, you would not claim they have some immaterial source of thinking.

> So, my position is that **thought is neither created by nor is taking place in the brain**.

You can have such a position, however the post lacks the part showing how you have come to such a conclusion.

---

> And my three part question is "**What** is thinking, **how** thought is created and **where** does it take place?".

It seems that any explanation not involving a brain would be entirely speculative, since what an experiment could you even set to test it? Not even an experiment, what would even be the observation of where it can be happening?

Comment: You asked.. "can there be a false justified belief"... ues.  When we think we have observationsl data support, but then have accidentl misinterpreted the dsta so it "says" something  it should not... examples observed red/blue shidt and our related conclusion of universal expansion.  Possibly a falsely justified belief, by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking is a grammatical expression of  perceptions,internal or external ,based on dictionary. Some kind of dictionary must be learned in order to think. The most basic dictionary is that of commonly understood definitions of pain and pleasure. Thinking is impermanent. It arises , changes and vanishes.

Thoughts are created using language. There are thoughts in Hindi language , Chinese language , Dog language, Lion language , Ant language , touch language , odour language etc …

Thoughts occur at six senses. There is a  language of tongue , language of touch , language of nose , language of eyes , language ears, language of mind. Mind is the king of all senses. Expression in mental language is what we call thoughts generally. But thoughts(as an expression) is expressed and understood by all senses.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to unpack here. Thought/thinking is a process, an action of what we would denote as mind/consciousness. At the most basic level a thought can be described as the recognition of a relationship between x and y. 'I think the tree is big' expresses the perception of x (tree) in relation to y (any other object that is smaller in size). It can be argued that thought is ultimately the relationship between Self and Other and that it is the notion of Self that is the crux of the matter.
Purely physicalist accounts (everything is brain) can, for the most part, easily accommodate thought as the process of thinking. X is perceived as proximal/distal to Self and so will fit into a broader pattern of other things related to self. The difficult question for the physicalist is how we understand the conception of self - usually referred to as consciousness. By a physicalist account of consciousness being purely a brain function we ought to be able, in theory at least, to predictably map the experience of self such that subjective experience does not exist. However, despite a plethora of models from the intersection of philosophy and neuroscience very little progress has been made and concerns around the implications on free will, abstract thought remain deeply problematic.
This is the hard problem of consciousness as most clearly articulated by David Chalmers. His response to this hard problem is to suggest that consciousness is extended so that we might say that the functions of thought reside in the brain (cognition), but the development of self/consciousness is extended out through conceptual tools, language, etc. This is obviously very broad brush strokes and you would have to read more around Chalmers to get the proper picture (Google Scholar, don't use Google!). More recently, though the roots are much older, is panpsychism which takes a more 'quantum' view of consciousness as basic properties. These non physicalist accounts are not without problems and are not wholly non physicalist. Neither do they constitute a return to dualism, though it has been argued that they are a slippery slope to dualism.
From studying philosophy of mind-consciousness-action it is clear that neither a wholly physicalist or dualist approach provide adequate explanatory power and it is increasingly likely that we are missing a part of the picture, be it some thing or more likely a way of perceiving the problem.
Your question on 'thought' - what is thought and how is it created - is relatively trivial. Thought is the construction of relationships based upon proximity to a Self created as sensory feedback via the brain. The more interesting question is how do we think without a conception of self, but how do we have a perception of self without thought? Physicalist accounts that self is a brain property (emergent or otherwise) are not wrong, but have implications that may be problematic and/or run counter to experience.
The dualism you prefer does not resolve any of the problems of consciousness, simply kicking the can down the road by replacing brain with soul or some other entity/property, where you will have to begin the work over again but this time have the added burden of proving that spirit/soul/etc. exist.
Consciousness is one of the more difficult areas of philosophy and entrenched positions of scientific absolutism or spiritualism are particularly unhelpful (see some of the holes Daniel Dennett or Pinker ends up in maintaining a hard physicalism). Language is key in all ways.

Answer (score -2):

I have ended my topic with the question: *"What is thinking, how thought is created and where does it take place?"*.
The description of the topic was already quite loaded so I have not added my own answer to the question, which I do here:

Thinking is done by and in the **mind**. The mind is not the brain. The mind is a communication and control system between the spirit (soul) and its environment. In order to achieve this, it uses the **brain**. One way in which this is done is by **thinking**. **Thought** has no mass or energy --so it is not part of the physical universe-- but it can produce mass and energy. This mass and energy is transmitted as signals and/or waves to the brain. The brain then process them and according to their kind, it sends itself signals and/or waves through neurons to the remaining body or as feedback, back to the mind.

This is how the system **mind-brain-body** works in general. It is of course much more complicated than it sounds!

I give a simple example below. Before that, I have to clarify one thing: When I say *"you"* I mean YOU as a person (spirit, soul), yourself, YOU as an awareness unit, who can be aware of being aware. You can think of it simply as a point of **view** (not "viewpoint"), a point from which you can be aware, observe, communicate, etc.

You are looking around in a park and you put your attention on a tree. You observe that tree. In order to do that, you need to use your eyes. You do that via your brain (communication system). Automatically, an image is formed in your mind. This image is also automatically compared to other similar images of trees. If you have seen this kind of tree in the past and/or you have some knowledge about that tree, you will recognize it as something familiar. If you have never seen that tree, it will be added to your "group" of known trees. This is one way of how knowledge is created. The process that the mind used for comparison, etc. is **thinking**. It may be very simple, i.e. it may end just there and you continue your walk in the park. But it may develop to a more complicated process. Examples:

You might not be sure if you have seen or know that tree. You might start thinking *"This tree reminds me of something"*, *"Where have I seen this tree before? Think! Think!"*, etc. And then you start a whole process of trying to identify that tree ... And, if the tree were something more important, e.g. a person, it could even become on obsession and you get stuck with thinking about it, trying to remember where have you seen that person atc. We know that well!

Now, if the tree is very familiar to you, you might remember that you have fell from such a tree when you were young, and start feeling some fear or other unpleasant emotion, pictures coming to your mind, and so on. On the other hand, that tree might remind you of a romantic place, a time you were in love, etc. which will create pleasant emotions.

This what one of the things a thought (thinking) can do. It can **create energy** in the form of emotions (waves) that you can feel in your **body**. The more "negative" these emotions are, the more dense is the energy felt in the body. It can be so dense so as to create a mass: intense anxiety produces adrenaline.

On the contrary, the more "positive" emotions are, the more fine the energy is. When you are happy, you feel very "light", even as if you are "flying". Yet, this is still an energy.

These energies are created my **thought**, which is created in and by the **mind**, which is part of the **spirit**, not the brain.

---

This is how I view and can explain what **thinking** is, how it us created and works and where it takes place. But if you want a more "standard" view, I will refer you to Descartes' and dualism. I use him as a reference because he is well known in here. (I could use philosophers and philosophic systems that are much nearer to my views, but they belong to the Eastern philosophy, which does not belong in here, as I can see from my 2+ months experience with TPF.)

Note: I am not a follower of Descartes or cartesianism. This is only a second view, in which mind is separated from the body-brain. These are **not my views**, which I have already described.

I include below just a few of quotations regarding Descartes, which I find representative of the subject of "thought".

---

"Initially, Descartes arrives at only a single principle: thought exists. *Thought cannot be separated from me, therefore, I exist* (Meditations on First Philosophy). Most famously, this is known as *cogito ergo sum*, (*I think, therefore I am*)."
(https://grants.hhp.uh.edu/clayne/HistoryofMC/HistoryMC/DescartesI.htm)

"Descartes defines *thought* (cogitatio) as *what happens in me such that I am immediately conscious of it, insofar as I am conscious of it*."
([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/René_Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes))

"*And so something that I thought I was seeing with my eyes is grasped solely by the faculty of judgment which is in my mind.*"
([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/René_Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes))

"Descartes tries to give a definition of *thought* in his Principles: By *thought* he means to refer to anything marked by awareness or consciousness. This does not just include reasoning or other such intellectual activities but also imagining, sensing, willing, believing, doubting, hoping, dreading, and all other mental operations."
(https://www.sparknotes.com/philosophy/principles/section3/)

Comment: The introduction of your answer reminds me of the book by Popper and Eccles https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Karl-Popper/dp/0415058988 This book triggered a long discussion, not only from philosophers but also from neuroscientists. Eccles' ideas were taken up also by Roger Penrose and expanded to a whole book. Nevertheless most neuroscientists are not convinced by Penrose's speculations based on ideas from quantum mechanics.

Comment: mind-brain-body problem??? Now we are three? It seems wrong: the brain is body; if it is not enough to account for thinking, then we have mind. See [Dualism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dualism/) and [Descartes' Dualism](https://books.google.it/books?hl=it&lr=&id=-qSvoR5tWIYC&oi=fnd&pg=PR9&dq=stanford+descartes+dualism&ots=l-Q5rdnr_V&sig=LS1QGqSWWf_Sf5SQE2WP6lfrXaM#v=onepage&q=stanford%20descartes%20dualism&f=false).

Comment: The mainstream idea is "The brain is the sole cause of thinking." Your idea is "The brain is merely a transmitter between the soul and the body." Not actually yours, it is popular in New Age circles. However, there is no experiment that would separate the two hypotheses. And the mainstream idea makes fewer assumptions, therefore is favored by Occam's razor.

Comment: If you could present a tiniest shred of evidence to support your claims, it would be really nice.

Comment: -1. I disagree vehemently with almost every sentence of your self-answer. I always comment when I downvote, to give the autor a chance to improve the answer, or just general feedback. In this case it is clear (from your Q, A and comments) that you are not interested in discussing this topic, but are in need of a platform for posting your standpoint. This is completely OK, there is nothing wrong with that. May I suggest using something like a blog/vlog, a Squarespace website, or a non-Q&A-based forum like Reddit etc.? I guarantee you, that would give you more satisfactory discourse.